# Error on hql Query object

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql

The various objects are all valid and used elsewhere in the app:

```
public virtual Discount SelectDiscountByUser(User currentUser)
{
    Query q = new Query();
    q.Criteria.Add(new Criteria("User.ID", CriteriaOperator.Equal, currentUser.ID));

    User user = DataContext.Load<User>(q);
   ...
}
```

I'm getting 2 compiler errors on the '.Load(q)' line

> Error 34  The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'myApp.DataAccess.IDataContext.Load(int)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments ...Facade\UserFacade.cs 100 25  myApp.Business
>
> Error 35  Argument 1: cannot convert
>   from 'myApp.DataAccess.Query' to
>   'int' ...Facade\UserFacade.cs 100 48  myApp.Business

where the line from the interface looks like:

```
     public interface IDataContext
     {
         EntityType Load<EntityType>(int ID) where EntityType : class, new();
         ...
```

I can clear the error conditions by return a list:

```
IList<User> user = DataContext.LoadList<User>(q);
```

and i can work with that list (return user[0].SubscriptionDiscount;) but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Load<User>(q.UniqueResult<User>());

Answer (score 1):

The interface method you have outlined above takes an integer and you are trying to pass it a Query object.  Seems like a pretty cut and dry issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both Cole and binaryhowl explained the problem, but you are complicating things unnecessarily.

- You already have a User instance, why do you need a new one?
- You can use `session.Load<EntityType>(ID)` or `session.Get<EntityType>(ID)` depending on what you really want to accomplish. There's no need for a query when you already know the Id.